# set wallpaper in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, set, wallpaper

**I want to code or open source file in as3
  For example, to save the image in the stage in Flash and make it a background in desktop or background in phone
Using the button
thanks**

Comment: This site requires specific questions. So first you have to tell us what you tried already. And what the problem/issue is.

Comment: there is no built in flash function to make an image as wallpaper. Maybe try to make an ANE : [native extension infos](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html)

Comment: But how to do that
Any other program
Is there an example of an open file

Comment: How do I do this by apk

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this extension, they have a demo (with some limitations, but works)

1- Download this extension [here](http://flashvisions.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/WallpaperManager_demo.zip)

2- Edit your AndroidManifest.xml and add this permission:

3- Try this code:

```
   //checking if extension is supported
   if (WallpaperManager.getInstance().isSupported())
   {
        var scale:Boolean;
        // default value is always false
        WallpaperManager.getInstance().setWallpaperFromPath(IMAGE_NATIVE_PATH, scale);
        // Pass native path of a image on device
   }
```

Thank you very much
Explain to me the steps I am a novice in programming
And any program I use to implement it

Comment: Thank you very much Explain to me the steps I am a novice in programming And any program I use to implement it